# ipengine does not keep running after closing SSH session

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel

I'm trying to run a couple of remote servers with `ipcontroller` and `ipengine`. So I start a single process with `ipcontroller` on "master" node, which I will be running ipython notebook on at the end.

Running `ipengine` on remote hosts goes smoothly thanks to lots of available tutorials. After running `ipenigne` for each host based on their number of CPUs, I use `disown -a` to avoid closing running `ipengine` in the background. However for some reason they do not keep running after closing the SSH session. I have even used `nohup` command but again a similar behaviour. I would appreciate any input on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use screen. Its should be installed on any linux distribution.
It will keep the session running after you disconnecting the ssh.
Here is a tutorial I googled for you:
http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen